# Checking for time

Tags: validation, datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have a form field which may have a date and may have a time in it. I need to confirm that both a date and time are present.

```
 <input type="text" name="transdate" ... />
```

I can use `isDate(form.transdate)` to check if there is a date, but it does not check if there is a time. I wish there was a `isTime()` function.

**Addendum**

The date time fields can be made to have

[image]

These fields are concatinated via

```
 date_cat = "#form.trans_date# #form.trans_date_h#:#form.trans_date_m# #form.trans_date_t#";
```

When I run this code:

```
cat: #date_cat# isValid(date): #isValid('date', date_cat)# isValid(time): #isValid('time', date_cat)#
```

I get

cat: 12/05/2018 :24 PM isValid(date): YES isValid(time): YES

Comment: You might be able to use `isValid(myDate,"datetime_object")`. Or `parseDateTIme(myDate)` and then do some magic on it.

Comment: Do you have a fixed format that the values will be in or is it a free form entry?

Comment: @Shawn, on any of the pulldown menus, the top is blank. Date is not a field that is required over all. If a user puts in one, then the entire thing needs to be a valid date time

Comment: But are they able to enter any text they want in the date or time, or does the application specify it? If the format of date and time is controlled by the application, then it's a lot easier to parse it, since you can specify the expected format of that string. Do you have an example of the form field where it is entered? <<< Nevermind. Just saw your update to the question. It was getting filtered out here.  So each of those fields comes through the form in a separate field? If you don't select a time value (like hour above), is it getting set to an empty string?

Comment: Beautiful: `isValid("time","12/05/2018 :24 PM")` gives me `YES` in CF2016 and CF11&10, but `NO` in CF2018. (And `false` in Lucee 5)

Comment: I like the `no` answer much better.

Comment: Then simply upgrade to CF2018 or Lucee. No biggie, right? :-)

Comment: Are you able to validate before you concat it to a string?

Comment: That is the approach I am ending up using. CF2018 is going to happen within the next 6 months. I don't want to use something that will change behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people hate regular expressions. I love them. Why not just check the concatenated string?

```
dtRegEx = "^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/[1-9][0-9]{3} (0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm)$";

if (reFind(dtRegEx, date_cat) and isDate(date_cat)) {
    // valid datetime
} else {
    // invalid datetime
}
```

## RegEx Breakdown

```
^
    string has to start with the whole pattern

(0[1-9]|1[0-2])
    month in range from 01 to 09 or 10 to 12

/
    date delimiter

(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])
    day in range from 01 to 09, 10 to 29 or 30 to 31

/
    date delimiter

[1-9][0-9]{3}
    year in range from 1000 to 9999

space
    space, literally

(0[0-9]|1[0-2])
    hour in range from 00 to 09 or 10 to 12

:
    time delimiter

[0-5][0-9]
    seconds in range from 00 to 59

space
    space, again

(am|pm)
    the meridiem stuff you guys from US and UK like so much :P

$
    string has to end with the whole pattern
```

> Note that the above pattern could still have you end up with invalid day ranges like `02/31/2018`, that's why you should still check with `isDate()`.

Comment: Good explanation.  Looks like the description of `^` was left off by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I addressed it, I validated the fields before the concatenation

```
if (form.trans_date_h == "" || form.trans_date_m == "" || form.trans_date_t == "") {
   // error handling here
```

Then did the concatenation

```
date_cat = "#form.trans_date# #form.trans_date_h#:#form.trans_date_m# #form.trans_date_t#";
```

Comment: After once again falling down the rabbit hole of date handling (thanks btw), using Alex's RegEx is probably the best way to validate your string. Especially if you know the incoming format to expect. I played around with `parseDateTime()`, and it gave me correct results on your example. But it got pretty wonky when I threw it out-of-range datetimes, like `13/35/0031 25:43 PM`. CF was actually able to parse that into a datetime object. So now I have to look at what it's doing to find out why. Thanks again for the homework. :-/ https://trycf.com/gist/84f7a34fad1a93f8bca24cf6952f7c29/acf2016

Comment: @Shawn - The wacky date is probably parsed because CF uses SimpleDateFormat beneath the covers, and it defaults to `setLenient(true)`. Seems to translate the year "0031" into 1931 (which makes sense, 2 digit year), and then rolls over the extra days to `1932-02-05 14:12:00`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)

Comment: @Ageax CF 2016 stopped using SimpleDateFormat after Update 3. Or at least Adobe's docs say it did. Honestly, I've always taken dates (in just about any language I've used) with a grain of salt. The only consistent thing I've seen is that they simply don't make sense and need to be watched like a hawk. You would think that something with its own ISO standard wouldn't be such a pain to work with. :-|

Comment: @Shawn - Wow..  had no idea about that change. Wonder what they are using instead. Hopefully not home grown validation, because given how lenient things like IsDate are, that would be truly frightening ;)

Comment: @Ageax I know. Just when I'd gotten used to SimpleDateFormat, they bailed on it. But considering that CF isn't really a case-sensitive language and Java is, it kinda makes sense. Especially since not all of CF's date formatting functions relied on SimpleDateFormat. But of all the times to decide not to worry about "backwards compatibility", that was an odd route to choose. CF will lose out on a lot of date meaning if it treats `yyyy` and `YYYY` the same. :-/